# Discovering Quadratic Reciprocity

Tags: number-theory, intuition, motivation, quadratic-reciprocity

Is there anything similar to [this](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/cubic.html) (page written by Field Medalist Timothy Gowers) for quadratic reciprocity ?

I mean, the link there explains how you can figure out the solution of cubic equation by yourself without having a suddent flash of inspiration/ genius genes. Is there some similar guide for quadratic reciprocity ?

Comment: Please, explain **here** what is your question.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Done.

Comment: I speak for myself alone on this, but your question is pretty unclear. Could you please use jargon more specific than “anything” and “this”?

Comment: I think the question seems pretty clear: how would you discover quadratic reciprocity? What is the intuition behind quadratic reciprocity? I tend to learn a lot from questions like this, because for some reason the question "how could I have thought of this" often seems to be neglected in textbooks.

Comment: This isn't really an answer and I'm certainly not an expert on this, so feel free to wait until more experienced people show up. But as far as I can tell, the way Euler, Gauss, Legendre, etc. learned about quadratic reciprocity was just by doing tons of calculations. Do calculations, make tables, look for patterns. Gauss' first proof (in Disquisitiones Arithmeticae) is a long and convoluted argument that uses induction, splitting the inductive step into something like eight different cases! That sounds like a proof you'd come up with believing that the statement is true, but not knowing "why".

Comment: (cont.) In particular, you would believe the statement, but not know why it was true, if you were convinced of it by numerical evidence. I'm told Gauss made conjectures about the Prime Number Theorem, not because he was a genius with some innate understanding of prime numbers, but because he had access (presumably through local academic libraries) to tables of prime numbers; he opened up such tables and looked for numerical patterns, and spotted (and this is where the genius *might* come in, depending on how long it took him) a certain pattern of growth in the number of primes less than $x.$

Comment: @littleO "how would you discover quadratic reciprocity?" would have been a clear question, but the OP didn't ask it. Many would like to get explained something in so simple terms that they believe they could have discovered that, but they couldn't. People who aren't able to ask a clear question won't discover anything. Discoveries come from own effort, not from consuming simple explanations. Quadratic reciprocity **is** more complex than cubic equations.

Comment: @WillR   I read somewhere that finding primes of the form $x^2+ky^2$ is somehow related with QR, and well I did lot of calculation in python, and progressed not very far except the trivial observation finding that except some very small primes, all primes of the form $x^2+ky^2$ are all primes equivalent to some number modulo some number. (eg when $k=1$, all primes of that form are all primes equivalent to 1 modulo 4)

Comment: @littleO Yes, that's exactly my question, and I don't know why Prof. Victor is interpreting that otherwise.

Comment: @AlexKChen: I'm not sure you've quite understood. Imagine you don't know anything about quadratic reciprocity; in particular, you don't even know whether or not any such law exists. But, for example, you might think to yourself "I wonder: is there a general way to solve quadratic congruences?" That is, how can we find solutions to a congruence of the form $x^{2}\equiv a\pmod{m}.$ Here $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: (cont.) So you start looking: there are only finitely many possibilities to check up to congruence, so for each $a$ and each $m$ (starting with $a=0,m=2$) you just go through one by one and find all the solutions (or perhaps you have a computer to do it for you, but Euler and Gauss didn't). You make tables listing all the solutions for a given $m.$ You do calculations for a looong time: maybe your tables go up to $m=500$ or more! And then you sit down, for a long time, and look for patterns. That's how a theorem like quadratic reciprocity would be *found.*

Comment: @WillR No well, that's how I often learn NT- by going over the historical questions in python. But unfortunately, spotting patterns in problems like such that given integer $(a,b)$ with $gcd(a,b) = 1$, find smallest $k$ such that $a^k \equiv 1 \mod b$ is easy, you can guess it's divisor of $\phi(b)$ by varying the number of distinct prime divisors of $b$. But for QR, I don't see any pattern even trying exactly what you told - the only pattern I saw that primes having $-1$ as a quadratic residue are all primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, but spotting this is easy considering $\Phi_{4}(x)$.

Comment: "If $p$ or $q$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ then: $x^{2}\equiv q\pmod{p}$ is solvable if and only if $x^{2}\equiv p\pmod{q}$ is solvable. If $p$ and $q$ are congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ then: $x^{2}\equiv q\pmod{p}$ is solvable if and only if $x^{2}\equiv p\pmod{q}$ is not." This is the kind of statement that one might "spot", eventually, if you calculate enough and look for long enough. I guess also it's about mindset: it's much easier to spot rules like this if you're used to doing such calculations.

Comment: @WillR That...looks like an unspotted information ! Thanks for it. BTW, I think then I should practice such numberical experiments more often.

Comment: @AlexKChen: It's something that is not really taught to us formally, but researchers must do it all the time. When I learned about QRL in a university number theory class, it was kind of a let down: I had heard and was told that this was an important theorem, and then the proof was meaningless and the result seemed like it was pulled out of a hat. It took me a long time to realize that to discover such a result must take nothing more than perseverance and an acquaintance with the necessary calculations that one could never really hope to achieve in an elementary number theory class.

Answer (score 4):

There is a book by David Marshall, Edward Odell, and Michael Starbird called ["Number Theory Through Inquiry"](https://www.maa.org/press/books/number-theory-through-inquiry). Chapter 7 is about quadratic reciprocity. It's sort of guided inquiry. The authors suggest questions for the reader, such as looking for patterns in certain tables. So the reader has some guidance and is not just completely on her own. But on the other hand there are a lot of exercises and theorems to be proven; the authors give the reader an opportunity to develop everything. Perhaps this book might fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of this paper http://www.math.ubc.ca/~belked/lecturenotes/620E/Frei%20-%20The%20Reciprocity%20Law%20from%20Euler%20to%20Eisenstein.pdf shows you how the QR law was discovered historically and shows the path all the way back to Diophantus.

It seems that the first question explicitly stated that is equivalent to a case of QR is

p is an odd prime of the form $x^2+ y^2$ with x, y integers $\iff$ p is equal to 1 mod 4.

This leads to the more general question:

Given $N\in \mathbb{Z}$, describe the primes $p \notin 2$ for which $p = x^2 + Ny^2$.

This was considered by Fermat and studied carefully by Euler and leads to the full QR theorem whereas the question for sum of two squares leads to the evaluation of the quadratic character of -1 mod p only.

Answer (score 0):

The first chapter of Cox's book, "[Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118390180)", discusses the origins of quadratic reciprocity, and shows through the discussion and by extended examples how Euler was led to discover quadratic reciprocity from considerations of solutions to this equation for various $n$.